# Is there any way to validate a X509Certificate2 offline in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, x509

We are making an auto updating app and we need to make sure that the setup archives are what they are supposed to be, so we check file integrity and signing, but also is needed to give the option of executing the app on Offline mode, Is there any way to validate a X509Certificate2 offline in C#?

Comment: The problem is that the certificate *could* have been revoked. In this case, you cannot know it offline, you must connect to the revoked certificate list server. Also, validity of server depends on time. If you are offline, you can fake time. If you want to validate the time, you must connect to a trusted external time server.

Comment: related : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/141311/is-certificate-validation-done-completely-local